# How can I recover the passphrase (not the password) of sda5_crypt

Tags: boot, password, encryption, ecryptfs, passphrase

I have a partition encrypted with `sda5_crypt`, where I need to input a password on boot to unlock the partition. I have the password and I login normally. But I need the passphrase for recovery to save it somewhere safe. I think it's the passphrase after the key derivation function, that one stores for emergencies. Where can I find this?

This: `ecryptfs-unwrap-passphrase` doesn't work. Apparently this is only for home directory encryption.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If, when installing, you chose to encrypt a FULL PARTITION, most likely you are using LUKS encryption and not ECRYPTFS.

With LUKS there is no passphrase wrapping AFAIK and that's why

```
ecryptfs-unwrap-passphrase .ecryptfs/wrapped-passphrase
```

does not work when run from your home directory.

In the Ubuntu setup, ECRYPTFS encrypts just a folder. you can choose whether that folder is going to be your home folder or a Private folder inside your home folder.

Just to make sure you are not using ECRYPTFS, look for a hidden folder, in your home directory, named .ecryptfs (could be a symlink). In the case there is no such a folder, you are not using ECRYPTFS and the wrapped passphrase does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using LUKS, it sounds like you want to get the master key, using the `cryptsetup` command and

> ```
> luksDump <device>
> ```
>
> Dump the header information of a LUKS device.
>
> If  the  --dump-master-key  option  is  used, the LUKS device master key is dumped
>    instead of the keyslot info. Beware that the master key cannot be changed and  can
>                 be  used to decrypt the data stored in the LUKS container without a passphrase and
>                 even without the LUKS header. This means that if the master  key  is  compromised,
>                 the whole device has to be erased to prevent further access. Use this option carefully.
>
> In order to dump the master key, a passphrase has to be supplied, either  interactively or via
>   `--key-file`